Movie about group therapy for murderers
I'm looking for the name of a movie where a guy wakes up in a room with a TV where a guy on the screen tells him he is dead and has murdered his wife. Then he sees how he died and killed his wife. He claims it was an accident, he was reaching for the phone, he didn't mean to suffocate her. It continues and he is told to go join the "group". It's like group therapy for murderers. "Hi my name is _____ and I killed my parents." This is how it happened.
Robert Pattinson is that character. Then the original guy is told (by a lady in a TV) to tell his story. He won't admit why he is there. I can continue to describe more of the movie but is this ringing a bell for anyone?
Julianne Moore plays a young Mom who hanged herself from a tree in her front yard in front of her daughters. 

"I can continue to describe more of the movie" - Yes, please go ahead and describe everything you remember and that may help identification. And have you tried looking into Pattinson's or Moore's filmography if you're so sure they were part of it? What does it say?

You have misidentified the people starring in the film.
However, the 2014 film "Cruel and Unusual" fits your description of the movie.
It is a Canadian movie, in which the protagonist wakes after accidentally killing his wife and dies himself, and a figure on a television orders him to group therapy with other murderers/suicides, one of which is a woman that hanged herself in front of her daughters.

Concur. This exactly describes "Cruel & Unusual". I don't think Julianne Moore has ever hanged herself in a film.

@moviegique - Not that I could recall, either. At first I thought it might be the one she was in with Jonathan Rhys Meyers, he has a vague resemblence to Pattinson, but the plot didn't fit.
